# How small must $x$ be to have $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}$ accuracy?

Tags: real-analysis

> For small values of $x$, how good is the approximation $cos(x)\approx 1$? How small must $x$ be to have $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}$ accuracy?

My teacher told me, it would be easier to do the second part of the question first, so I need to find out how small $x$ be to have $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}$ accuracy

So as far as I understand, I need to solve for $x$ in the following equation

$|cos(x)-1|<\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8} \Rightarrow \\
|x| < \ arccos(1-\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}) \Rightarrow \\
x \in \ (-arccos(1-\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}),arccos(1-\frac{1}{2} \cdot 10^{-8}))$

but that just seems like a messy answer. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series of $\cos$? [Or generally, the Taylor formula for $k$ times differentiable functions?]

Comment: I was told it could be solved without using Taylor. I know that $cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - ...$, but that seems tougher to solve for $x$?

Comment: @Jta You don't have to solve that for $x$. Just think about how many terms you need for the accuracy you want.

Comment: If you want _exact_ bounds, then you need $\arccos$. But typically in such questions one wants an approximate sufficient bound. Some $c > 0$ such that $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant c \implies \lvert 1 - \cos x\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}10^{-8}$, and such that $c$ is simple, yet close to the exact bound. Here, if you use $$1 \geqslant \cos x \geqslant 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!},$$ …

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, this is probably what the teacher had in mind, comparing $\frac 1 2 10^{-8}$ and $\frac1 2 x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't learned about Taylor series.

Will you accept that $\sin x \approx x$ when $x$ is small?
and $\sin x < x$ for all $x.$

You can do this geometrically, plot your unit circle and see that for small $x$, the distance traveled about the $x$ axis is very nearly equal to the length of the curve.

$\cos x = \sqrt{1-sin^2 x}$

$\cos x \approx (1-x^2)^{\frac 12}$

In fact, $\cos x$ is slightly greater than (1-x^2)^{\frac 12}$ when $x$ is small, but we will stick with this approximation.

Now do a binomial expansion on $(1-x^2)^{\frac 12}$

$(1-x^2)^{\frac 12} 1 - \frac 12 x^2$

$cos x \approx  1 - \frac 12 x^2 $

Your error is: 
$\frac 12 x^2 < \frac 12 10^{-8}$

If $|x| < 10^{-4}, |\cos x - 1| < \frac 12 10^{-8}$