# How small must $x$ be for the error of $\cos(x) \approx 1$ to be below a certain threshold

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

I might be missing some background knowledge on this subject, but nevertheless I am interested. In some cases like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919504/how-small-must-x-be-to-have-frac12-cdot-10-8-accuracy), the answers talk about finding the taylor series for $\cos(x)$ and then substituting the first two terms of the series in instead of $\cos(x)$ i.e in the link they solve for $x$ in

$$\frac{x^2}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-8}$$

Rather than 
$$1-\cos(x) \leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-8}$$

So my question is - why is this allowed? And why not include the 3rd term from the Taylor series as well?

Comment: Because the "tail" of the series (all terms after the first two) will not sum to more that the acceptable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed because the Taylor series for $\cos x$ is an alternating series, and they use Leibniz' theorem for alternating series: the error is bounded by the first missing term (in absolute value) and has the same sign.

Comment: As long as the terms are decreasing in absolute value.

Comment: @martycohen: Yes, but in the case of  $\cos x$, they're ultimately decreasing, and I suppose $|x|<1$ in practise.

Comment: The Lagrange remainder gives a cleaner argument in this particular case: $|\cos(x)-1|=|\cos(x)-1-0x|=\cos(\xi) \frac{x^2}{2}$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$. In particular, the $|x|<1$ assumption is not technically necessary to get $|\cos(x)-1| \leq x^2/2$, though of course without this assumption the bound gets rather bad.